# How to combine WCF project and simple class library in one VS project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wcf, class

I am working on a service that uses a class library to fetch information from my database, but I am having problems combining the two projects.

I have made a simple WCF service and moved all service's files to a folder called `Service`. All files in folder `Service` are part of `ServiceA` namespace.

I have also made a folder called `AD` and moved my class library and database file to this folder. All files that have to be located in this `AD` folder have to be part of `AD_X` namespace (including the database file).

Now the problem is that if I try to build this project, **then VS2010 creates a new `Web.Config` file in the project's root directory. I want to keep `Web.config` file located in `Service` folder together with other service's files.**

I have problems accessing my database file from my class library. If I create a `connectionstrings` section in `Web.config` folder and move it to the project's root folder, then I can access it, but I want to keep the database together with my class library. **How can I create for example `App.config` file in `AD` folder, so that I could create `connectionstrings` section and afterwards use my database file in my class library?**

This is an overview of my current project:

```
Project X
-- Properties
-- -- AssemblyInfo.cs
-- References
-- -- (assemblies)
-- AD
-- -- ADUM.edmx
-- -- -- ADUM.Designer.cs
-- -- Authentication.cs
-- App_Data
-- Service
-- -- IServiceA.cs
-- -- ServiceA.svc
-- -- -- ServiceA.svc.cs
-- -- Web.config
-- -- -- Web.Debug.config
-- -- -- Web.Release.config
```

Comment: One option would be to create a Solution and add the class library project and your WCF service project to the solution, then add the library project as a reference to the WCF service.  Note that class libraries do not use their own app.config file, but the config file (app or web) of the application that is using the library.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim. It does work! I will still wait for an answer on how to combine two namespaces in one project, but this is definitely a solution that is working.